# NSFileManager:enumeratorAtURL: returns a different form of URL to NSFileManager:URLForDirectory

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsfilemanager

If I fetch my sandbox's Application Support directory using `NSFileManager:URLForDirectory` then I get back the following URL:

```
file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/EA80DE91-394C-4EAB-B269-1081C859BB0F/Library/Application%20Support/
```

However if I use `NSFileManager:enumeratorAtURL` to search the directory I get back URLs of the form:

```
file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/EA80DE91-394C-4EAB-B269-1081C859BB0F/Library/Application%20Support/
```

This is causing me problems because I'm doing URL search/replace manipulations and the difference causes a mismatch. I've run into this sort of difference elsewhere previously and my solution then was to use the path of the urls (using `NSURL:path`) instead of the raw URLs, however that won't work in this situation as the paths produced are:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/EA80DE91-394C-4EAB-B269-1081C859BB0F/Library/Application Support
/private/var/mobile/Applications/EA80DE91-394C-4EAB-B269-1081C859BB0F/Library/Application Support/
```

What I am trying to do is this: I can have any number of files in my Application Support directory with the same name but different locations, and I need to extract the path  relative to the Application Support directory. i.e. if I have the following

```
/Application Support/abc/file.dat
/ApplicationSupport/abc/def/file.dat
```

I want to be able to extract "abc" and "abc/def". I was doing this using the following code:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLIsRegularFileKey];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnumerator = [self.fileManager enumeratorAtURL:[MyManager appSupportDirectory]
                                          includingPropertiesForKeys:keys
                                                             options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                                        errorHandler:nil];
    for (NSURL *url in dirEnumerator)
    {
        if ( NSOrderedSame == [[url lastPathComponent] caseInsensitiveCompare:kFilename])
        {
            NSString *appSupportPath = [[MyManager appSupportDirectory] path];
            NSString *pathToFile = [url path];
            pathToFile = [pathToFile URLByDeletingLastPathComponent];
            NSString *subPath = [pathToFile  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:appSupportPath withString:@""];
```

(MyManager:appSupportDirectory calls NSFileManager:URLForDirectory: using NSApplicationSupportDirectory)

This works fine on the simulator where `enumeratorAtURL:` and `URLFOrDirectory:` return identical paths, but due to their differences on hardware it fails.

Is there a way to get `enumeratorAtURL:` and `URLForDirectory:` to return identical paths, or if not is there an alternative elegant way of extracting the subpaths to what I am currently doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to switch to doing this instead:

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [self.fileManager enumeratorAtPath: [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Library/Application Support/"]];
```

Comment: I had the same problem. The fileManager's contentsOfDirectoryAtURL returns an URL with /private/. And I had trouble comparing to my URL record in database.

Answer (score 8):

`var` is symlinked to `/private/var/`

calling `[url URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath]` fixes it.

see [What does the /private prefix on an iOS file path indicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992834/what-does-the-private-prefix-on-an-ios-file-path-indicate/16026416) for more discussion.