# How do you create an NSURL from a string containing spaces?

Tags: ios

The result of this code is that url is null

```
NSString* home = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Library/Application Support/"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:home];
```

and so is this:

```
NSString* home = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Library/Application Support/"];
home = [home stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:home];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question is not about creating an URL from a **string** containing spaces, but from a **path string** containing spaces.

For a path, you should not use `URLWithString`. Mac OS X and iOS include convenience functions for building NSURLs for file paths that handle this and more for you automatically. Use one of them instead.

Apple's documentation for `[NSURL fileURLWithPath: path]` says:

> This method assumes that *path* is a directory if it ends with a slash. If *path* does not end with a slash, the method examines the file system to determine if *path* is a file or a directory. If *path* exists in the file system and is a directory, the method appends a trailing slash. If *path* does not exist in the file system, the method assumes that it represents a file and does not append a trailing slash.
>
> As an alternative, consider using `fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:`, which allows you to explicitly specify whether the returned `NSURL` object represents a file or directory.

Also, you should be using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` to find the Application Support directory.

Putting this all together, you'd end up with something like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                     NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *applicationSupportDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: applicationSupportDirectory isDirectory: YES];
```

Source:

- [iOS Developer Library: NSURL Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-BAJBGFBJ)

Answer (score 4):

You actually need to *add* percent escapes, not remove them:

```
NSString* home = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Library/Application Support/"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[home stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSLog(@"%@", url);
```

which prints:

```
2012-07-18 13:44:54.738 Test[1456:907] /var/mobile/Applications/FF6E6881-1D1B-4B74-88DF-06A2B62CCFE6/Library/Application%20Support
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 2.0 version:**

```
let encodedPath = path?.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
```

Answer (score 1):

First, if you're actually trying to get the application support directory for your application, use the appropriate method for the job (in this case, on `NSFileManager`) and work on the URL directly:

```
NSURL* appSupport = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory: NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:NULL];
```

If you really want to build a path, then use the appropriate initializer, in this case, tell the URL that it's a file path URL so that it will deal with spaces naturally and you can probably build up the URL path (this example is more like your code above):

```
NSString* home = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Library/Application Support/"];
// Here, use the appropriate initializer for NSURL
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:home];
```

Now, URL will be properly percent encoded and you won't have any problem (it will not be nil when returned).

Comment: If the URL created via URLForDirectory: is fed into NSFileManger:enumeratorAtPath: (after first converting it to a string using absoluteString) then the returned NSDirectoryEnumerator is empty. I was originally using URLForDirectory in combination with enumeratorAtURL: but could not get things to work with what I was doing so switched to enumeratorAtPath, but that will not work with URLForDirectory it seems. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546974/nsfilemanagerenumeratoraturl-returns-a-different-form-of-url-to-nsfilemanager

Comment: @ChrisP.Bacon Again, it's an issue of using the correct API. If you have a file URL, you should not convert it to a path by calling `-absoluteString`, you *should* convert it to a path by calling the `-path` method.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.0 version:**

```swift
let urlStrWithSpace = "path/test url"

guard let formattedUrl = urlStrWithSpace
.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else { return }

let sharePath = NSURL(string: formattedUrl)
```