# NSFileManager not providing correct URLs when calling URLsForDirectory:inDomains:

Tags: url, ios7, nsfilemanager, directory

I want to start off by saying that this block of code worked before the implementation and roll out of `iOS 7`.

Basically I have a file name that I'm looking for in the `NSCachesDirectory`, so I create a URL object as my search item.  Then I enumerate the directories (using the same NSFileManager object) and look for file names that equal each other, and that's how I know the file exists.

```
+ (BOOL)itemExistsInMemory:(NSString *)itemName
```

{
    BOOL itemExists = NO;

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

NSArray *mySandboxDirs = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];//get the directories for the application

NSURL *searchForURL = [[mySandboxDirs lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", itemName, FileNameAppendix]];//look for the specific file

NSArray *enumerator = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:[mySandboxDirs lastObject] includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLNameKey, NSURLIsRegularFileKey, NSURLCreationDateKey, nil] options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles error:nil];

for(NSURL *url in enumerator)
{//find out if any of the URLs within the NSCachesDirectory match what we're looking for
    NSNumber *isRegularFile = nil;
    [url getResourceValue:&isRegularFile forKey:NSURLIsRegularFileKey error:NULL];

    if([isRegularFile boolValue])
    {

        if([url relativeString] isEqualToString:[searchForURL relativeString]])
        {
            itemExists = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
}

return itemExists;
```

}

The file DOES INDEED EXIST in the `NSCachesDirectory`, however, the code doesn't find it because the searchForURL object was created without a path component (the path component is private/...).  Why?  Even stranger is that I save the data to a URL that's created with the

```
[[mySandboxDirs lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", itemName, FileNameAppendix]];
```

instruction!  So it doesn't include the private/ path component in the URL, but when I write the data with [NSData writeToURL:] it "redirects" it to the private/ directory.

So why can't `[NSFileManager URLsForDirectory: inDomains:]` get me the correct directories for `NSCachesDirectory`?

More info moved from the comment for better formatting:

By the way, here's an example of what's contained in the URLs I'm creating and looking for ->

When I create a URL for saving:

```
file:///var/mobile/Applications/C63B378E-5EBE-417C-A465-8C3A3DCE013A/Library/Cac‌​hes/Experimental%20Post.cnt
```

When I create a URL for searching:

```
file:///var/mobile/Applications/C63B378E-5EBE-417C-A465-8C3A3DCE013A/Library/Cac‌​hes/Experimental%20Post.cnt
```

What the enumerator sees:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/C63B378E-5EBE-417C-A465-8C3A3DCE013A/Lib‌​rary/Caches/Experimental%20Post.cnt
```

I could simply take the URLs that the enumerator comes up with and remove the "private" part of the URL so that the strings match and I can proceed, but I'd like to understand why this is happening.  Please also note that this only happens when you put the app on an iDevice since the directories are different than when you simulate it with the `iOS Simulator`.

Thanks to anyone that can be of assistance.

Comment: By the way, here's an example of what's contained in the URLs I'm creating and looking for -> when I create a URL for saving: file:///var/mobile/Applications/C63B378E-5EBE-417C-A465-8C3A3DCE013A/Library/Caches/Experimental%20Post.cnt
When I create a URL for searching:  file:///var/mobile/Applications/C63B378E-5EBE-417C-A465-8C3A3DCE013A/Library/Caches/Experimental%20Post.cnt
What the enumerator sees:  file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/C63B378E-5EBE-417C-A465-8C3A3DCE013A/Library/Caches/Experimental%20Post.cnt

Comment: It is better to edit your question with more information so it can be more reasonably formatted. I just added it to the question.

Comment: Sorry.  Thanks for doing that for me.

Answer (score 2):

/var is a symlink to /var/private, use `[NSURL URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath]` to resolve the symlink.

In your example:

```
for(NSURL *url in enumerator) {
  NSURL *resolvedSymlinksURL = [url URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath];
  ...
}
```

More detailled discussion: [What does the /private prefix on an iOS file path indicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992834/what-does-the-private-prefix-on-an-ios-file-path-indicate/16026416)

Answer (score 0):

in the `for` loop, see if the `url` object have some return characters (like `\r` or `\n`) and remove it before proceeding.

Comment: it doesn't.  See the additional information that Zaph added to the question.  I provided an example file that I'm searching for, and you can clearly see that the URL NSFileManager comes up with for me does not include the /private directory notation, but the enumerator has it.  You can also see that the enumerator found the file, but since the entire URL doesn't match, the code thinks it's not the right one.

Comment: Aahh! I didn't noticed the /private/ in the beginning of the url! the thing I suggested actually was a problem for me in `Cocoa` programming for `OSX`. but I don't have any experience in `iOS` file system! Sorry! :)