# iOS App groups - shared CoreData fails to open

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, watchkit, ios-app-group

I have an app with a **CoreData** database and access it using `UIManagedDocument`.
To share the data with the `Watchkit` app, I'm moving the database to a shared App Group.

The store is created correctly it seems, but after that it often becomes impossible to access it: the `UIManagedDocument` keeps trying to reconfigure the store, and `NSFileManager` doesn't find the file (with `fileExistsAtPath`).

The problem is in the database location - if I save it in the **documents** directory instead of the shared Group, it works without trouble. It's also not a problem of accessing it from both apps, even if I don't open the watch app at all the problem appears. The group is also working correctly for sharing `NSUserDefaults`.

Did anyone see similar problems? Is there any locking mechanism that I need to deal with in a specific way?
Any help will be greatly appreciated, I've been struggling a lot with this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I found that the storeURL would change (randomly) between these two:

```
file:///var/mobile/...
file:///private/var/mobile/...
```

I used `URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath` on the URL as specified in the following answer, and incredibly, it fixed it:
[What does the /private prefix on an iOS file path indicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992834/what-does-the-private-prefix-on-an-ios-file-path-indicate)

I'm assuming this is a system bug with the App Group paths... it seems that the different paths were causing the `persistentStoreCoordinator` to try to reopen the store when it was already open.