# NSDirectoryEnumerator: are the returned path relative?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, relative-path, nsfilemanager, absolute-path

According to the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSDirectoryEnumerator_Class/Reference/Reference.html), the paths returned by `NSDirectoryEnumerator` should be relative to the folder which is enumerated:

> An NSDirectoryEnumerator object enumerates the contents of a
>   directory, returning the pathnames of all files and directories
>   contained within that directory. These pathnames are relative to the
>   directory.

But, when I do

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [myFileManager enumeratorAtURL:URLFolder
                                     includingPropertiesForKeys:nil
                                                        options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                                   errorHandler:^BOOL(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
                                                               return YES ;}];
```

I get paths which are absolute!

**Is it normal or a known problem?**

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546974/nsfilemanagerenumeratoraturl-returns-a-different-form-of-url-to-nsfilemanager) may help

Comment: can you show what you do? How do you display the paths? can you show a few output examples?

Comment: Here is how I display the path:
`NSString *file;
 while ((file = [dirEnum nextObject])) NSLog(@"So ? %@", file) ;`

Here is the result : 
`file:///Users/colas/Library/Application%20Support/MyApp/aux/5553_uOEAoof/autosave/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/enumeratorAtURL%3aincludingPropertiesForKeys%3aoptions%3aerrorHandler%3a) is actually supposed to return absolute paths (see the discussion in the link). If you want relative path values, you can use [enumeratorAtPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/enumeratorAtPath%3a).

Comment: I don't see where they say it is actually supposed to return absolute paths. Anyway, thanks.